# Scrapy/LxmlLinkExtractor is appending same url path continuosly

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm getting the following url when i try to extract links from a webpage. Scrapy/LxmlLinkExtractor is appending a part of the url path again and again infinitely. How do I fix this?

'http://blogs.wsj.com/metropolis/2011/01/26/weather-journal-more-snow-than-expected-in-new-york-area/tab/2011/01/26/weather-journal-more-snow-than-expected-in-new-york-area/tab/2011/01/25/2011/01/25/2011/01/26/weather-journal-more-snow-than-expected-in-new-york-area/tab/2011/01/25/2011/01/26/weather-journal-more-snow-than-expected-in-new-york-area/tab/2011/01/26/weather-journal-more-snow-than-expected-in-new-york-area/tab/2011/01/26/weather-journal-more-snow-than-expected-in-new-york-area/tab/2011/01/25/2011/01/26/weather-journal-more-snow-than-expected-in-new-york-area/....'

I'm using `scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml.LxmlLinkExtractor` to extract links.

`lxml_link_extractor = LxmlLinkExtractor(allow_domains=['wsj.com']
                              )
lxml_link_extractor.extract_links(response)` #response is a standard Response given back to the spider from the middlewares

Comment: Please, show complete code, we can't help if you give us just this...

Comment: I just updated it

Comment: This is not complete spider code.